# How to design a table and other pieces of furniture?

Tags: modeling

I am a 50 plus year old.
I an trying to learn blender, so I can design tables etc, I have tried to watch videos but cant find the right ones.
I know i am the problem, I am a slow learner and do not understand things.
Can anyone help me, can you show me the videos to design a table please.

OK sorry, I want to design a Workshop table that I will then build, it will house a built-in table-saw, router and jigsaw, it will have wheels so I can move it around, I am working with 4 x 2 and plywood, I hope that helps, thank you everyone for your patience and efforts

Comment: Are you trying to design tables for manufacturing/actually being produced, or just computer visualizations?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial, its not a table but a chair. It helped me to dive in to blender modelling.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gi5Kwgkemjc

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your reply

Comment: thank you for your reply, I an starting from scratch, no blueprint, I have drawn by hand and have my measurements, I now want to do a digital plan, but I am struggling to even get started. It does not need fancy curves, in fact, it is almost all straight lines. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but... like... In order to help you, we really need to know if you're planning on designing the table for in-real-life construction, or just to have computer visualizations of how the table would look

Comment: Andrew's channel will be awesome and fun to learn. See https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOKHwx1VCdgnxwbjyb9Iu1g